# Erro no Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Estou tentando fazer uma pequena interação com o banco de dados MySQL mas quando eu executo a classe teste aparece o seguinte erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Mappings.(Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/util/List;Ljava/util/List;Lorg/hibernate/cfg/NamingStrategy;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/util/Map;)V
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.ExtendedMappings.(ExtendedMappings.java:43)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.createExtendedMappings(AnnotationConfiguration.java:125)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.addAnnotatedClass(AnnotationConfiguration.java:94)
>       at teste.main(teste.java:13)

Segue o códigos da conexão:

```
package com.cavalcanteTech.dao;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

/* @author Emanuel Cavalcante*/

public class HibernateUtil {

    public static final SessionFactory session = buildSession();

    private static SessionFactory buildSession() {

        try {
            Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            return cfg.buildSessionFactory();

        } catch (Throwable b) {

            System.out.println("Não deu \n" + b);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError();
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return session;
    }
}
```

Segue o meu modelo:

```
package com.cavalcanteTech.modelo;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/* @author Emanuel Cavalcante*/

@Entity
public class Cliente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "nome")
    private String nome;
    @Column(name = "endereco")
    private String endereco;
    @Column(name = "telefone")
    private String telefone;
    @Column(name = "dataDePagamento")
    private String dataDePagamento;
     //gets e sets
}
```

A minha classe ClienteDAO:

```
package com.cavalcanteTech.dao;

import org.hibernate.Session;

import com.cavalcanteTech.modelo.Cliente;

public class ClienteDao {
    private Session session;

    public void Inserir(Cliente cliente) {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            System.out.println("Passou1");
            session.beginTransaction();
            System.out.println("Passou1");
            session.save(cliente);
            System.out.println("Passou1");
            session.getTransaction().commit();

        } finally {
            session.close();

        }
    }
}
```

Agora, minha classe que executa o teste:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

import com.cavalcanteTech.dao.ClienteDao;
import com.cavalcanteTech.dao.HibernateUtil;
import com.cavalcanteTech.modelo.Cliente;

public class teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfiguration cfg = new AnnotationConfiguration();
        cfg.addAnnotatedClass(Cliente.class);
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
        ClienteDao dao = new ClienteDao();
        cliente.setDataDePagamento("3213");
        cliente.setEndereco("312321");
        cliente.setNome("432432");
        cliente.setTelefone("321312");
        cliente.setId(1);
        System.out.println(cliente.toString());
        dao.Inserir(cliente);
    }
}
```

Minhas bibliotecas usadas no projeto:
<kbd>[image: bibliotecas]</kbd>

E o meu hibernate.cfg.xml:
<kbd>[image: hibernate.cfg.xml]</kbd>

Já procurei esse erro em vários lugares, mas até agora não consegui resolver, se alguem souber o que eu estou fazendo de errado, agradeço desde já. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente você está usando a versão 3.2.4.

Para usar o método [**`AnnotationConfiguration#addAnnotatedClass()`**](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationConfiguration.html#addAnnotatedClass%28java.lang.Class%29) você precisa importar o arquivo jar do `hibernate-core` na versão 3.6.0 ou superior.

Comment: Então eu removo o hibernate3-3.2.4.sp1.jar e adiciono o hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar, teoricamente é pra da tudo certo?

Comment: Substitui e apareceu esse erro:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 ... 1 more

Answer (score 0):

Você deve trocar as configurações de bibliotecas, primeiro porque está com erro e segundo porque está bem desatualizada. Se estiver utilizando Maven, recomendo que pegue a versão 5.2.0.Final do Hibernate-Core neste link: [MVNRepository - Hibernate Core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core)

E a partir de certa versão do Hibernate, não se utiliza mais a classe AnnotationConfiguration, que foi movida para a classe Configuration. Tente realizar a configuração das sessions do Hibernate conforme código abaixo:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public static void configureSessionFactory() {
  try{
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost...");
    prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "root");
    prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "123");
    prop.setProperty("dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect");

    sessionFactory = new Configuration()
            .addPackage("pacote onde estao as entidades")
                .addProperties(prop)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Cliente.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(t);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esse problema é simplesmente um fato:

- A session factory, não conseguiu mapear os objetos @Entity
- Ou seja a factory, não reconhece essas classes

> cfg.addAnnotatedClass(Cliente.class);
>   Isso não esta surtindo efeito.

Dica procure por algum método igual o semelhante a isso

```
cfg.afterPropertiesSet();
// ou algo
cfg.buildSessionFactory();
```

Assim a session factory vai terminar de armar e sabe que tem mapeado o objeto **Cliente**